# Code-folding in Notepad++ with two-word keywords?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, code-folding

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) supports user-defined languages for syntax-highlighting and code-folding (v.2.1.0.12). However, my language has two-word keywords like "begin function" and "end function". Using quotation marks for those "open" and "close" keywords does not have the desired effect, they are not matched.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try **SynWrite** editor with its user configurable lexer: define block start with 2 tokens, block end with two tokens (or any number of tokens). See Readme folder with a tutorial.